# how to bring two td cells closer

Tags: html, css

for my website I'm trying to bring two td closer. They are so far apart, I've been trying to put the td with numbers and td with image together. This is the domain for my webiste: 
If you check the code, you can see it's horrible which is probably why I'm having such a hard time trying to bring two td closer.

To be more clear, what I'm trying to do is

```
<table>
        <td class="vert-align" style="padding:0;" >
 <div class="votes">
<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <br />

<span class="col-md-12" style="height:1px; font-family: 'Passion One', cursive; bottom:10px; padding-left:0.01em;


#and 
<td class="vert-align">

{% if post.main_image %}
      <h4 id="lineForUrl">
        <a href="{{ post.url }}" target="_blank" style="margin-left: 15px; text-decoration:none;"> <img src="{{post.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" height="75" width="75"/><span id="title-font" title="{{post.title}}">
          {{ post.title }}</span><span style="margin-left: 15px;" class="domain">({{ post.domain }})</span></a>
        <span class="discuss" style="color:red;"><a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">enter</a></span>
        <br />
        <span class="post-info">
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' post.moderator.user %}">{{ post.moderator.user }}</a>wrote
{% else %}
{{ post.moderator.user }}wrote
{% endif %}
<a href="/category/{{post.category}}">#{{post.category}}</a></span>
      </h4>
"><h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.get_vote_count }}</h4></span>     <br>

<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
          </td>
</table>

#closer
```

Comment: You are not closing your SECOND span tag after the <br /> (that might cause any other or this specific problem)

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS line (if I have correctly understood your problem)

```
#cell td.vert-align:first-child { width: 40px;}
```

It will get your `td` with numbers and `td` with images closer